# How to print 1 to 100 using ES6 map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How to print 1 to 100 using ES6 map function ? 
Note : Without using any loop or recursive thing.Use only map function.

Comment: Hi! Welcome! SO isn't a code writing service. It's a question and answer site used only to help people understand and resolve issues with their code. The problems with this question are that there is no code to show what you have tried, and because of that you obviously don't have a particular issue with that code that we can help to resolve.

Comment: `Array(100).fill( ).map( (_,i) => console.log( i + 1 ) );`, but map is the wrong function for this. `map` should only be used when you want to create a new array from applying a function to each element of the original array. `forEach` is much more appropriate when you want to simply perform an action for each element.

Comment: What is your aim in doing this? And a `map` is as  much as `forEach` a loop, with the addition that it creates a new array.

Answer (score 3):

Using `map`:

```
Array.apply(null, {length: 100}).map((value, index) => index + 1);
```

Using `from`:

```
Array.from(new Array(100),(val,index)=>index+1);
```

... and there are lot of techniques. Just google for "create range es6"

---

And even shorter:

```
[...Array(100)].map((_, i) => i+1);
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, you'll first need an array of 100 values.  A new array can be created and filled so we can then map over the values.  Once we have the array to map over, we can leverage the index of the array as the current numeric value we would like to output, with the exception of it being 0-based.  Due to the fact that index values are 0-based, we'll need to add 1 to the result to get a range from 1-100 (as opposed to 0-99).

```
new Array(100).fill().map((_, i) => console.log(i + 1));
```

The map function is typically used for returning an array, based on an existing array.  Since you do not need to return an array, it would be best for you to use forEach() instead.

```
new Array(100).fill().forEach((_, i) => console.log(i + 1));
```

Comment: thanks rob for your solution.